# An internal error occurred during: "Importing project to workspace..."

Tags: java, egit, spring-tool-suite

I have tried to import existing repository of Openshift.com to **STS 3.6.4** but I'm getting this error :
[image]

#### UPDATE

When I Start **STS 3.6.4** I get this error message.

 I have tried lots of time and searched the net, and even reinstalled windows but did not found and solution to this issue!!
How to resolve this?

Comment: Might be a problem with OpenShift plugin that contributed the wizard you're using to import the project... Perhaps OpenShift Eclipse plugin doesn't support the version of Eclipse that you have with your STS. Try STS on Eclipse Luna or something lower than Luna... Also try your OpenShift plugin with pure Eclipse Luna or Mars without STS